# How to create a list with strings and integers as its elements?

Tags: python, string, input, type-conversion

This sounds so simple, but I cannot find anything on how to do this on the internet. I've gone through documentation but that didn't help me.

I have to get inputs from the user to create a list. This is what I am using right now.

```
t = raw_input("Enter list items: ")
l = map(str,t.split())
```

But this is converting every element into  a string. If I use int in map function, then every element would be converted to int.

What should I do? Is there any other function that I am missing?

Comment: Check to see if the item is suitable to be an `int` and convert it if it is, if not leave it. It isn't rocket science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to only call `int` on the strings which contain nothing but numerical characters (this is determined by [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)):

```
t = raw_input("Enter list items: ")
l = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in t.split()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> t = raw_input("Enter list items: ")
Enter list items: 1 hello 2 world
>>> l = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in t.split()]
>>> l
[1, 'hello', 2, 'world']
>>>
```

Comment: Happy to have been of help!  Please do not forget to accept an answer by clicking the check next to it.  Doing so lets people know this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

use try/except.  Try to make it an int.  If that fails, leave it as a string.

```
def operation(str):
    try:
        val = int(str)
    except ValueError:
        val = str
    return val

t = raw_input("Enter list items: ")
l = map(operation,t.split())

print l
```

You can use a list comprehension rather than map for more "pythonic" code:

```
t = raw_input("Enter list items: ")
l = [operation(x) for x in t.split()]
```

Edit:  I like iCodez's better... the isDigit test is nicer than try except.